# Refused to display Oauth Twitter page in iframe because 'X-Frame-Options' is set to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: wordpress, grails, iframe, twitter, oauth

I am creating a website in Grails and I want to use my pages in iframe window. But when I open Oauth page for twitter in iframe it shows the error:

> Refused to display
>   'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=token' in a frame
>   because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

This error also occurred when I want to open google+, wordpress and youtube Oauth access pages in iframe.

In case of google+ :

> Refused to display
>   'https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.…%26hl%3Den%26from_login%3D1%26as%3D66a03fa55190219f&btmpl=authsub&hl=en_GB'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

In case of wordpress :

> Refused to display
>   'public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=33528&redirect_url=/login/oAuthCallBack&response_type=code&state=0001x02'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Please suggest any solution how can i open these pages in iframe.

Comment: Have you ever wondered, why you might not be allowed to display those pages in iframe elements?

Answer (score 0):

Well basically... you can't. And even if you get it working, it probably won't work on all browsers. For example, I once got around the SAMEORIGIN restriction in Goggle Chrome, but it flat out failed in Safari.

My solution was to abandon using an iframe.